# Looping until web page changes - access denied

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a loop to pause my sub until It changes the page. I keep getting "Access is denied" once the loop is supposed to end (once it reached the /get page).  Why does this occur? And is there a better way to tell when youve changed pages?  I do not believe I can use the document complete event effectively for what I am trying to do.

```
'axweb.navigate("my.url.com/")


    htmldoc = axWeb.Document.frames("Frame1").document

    If htmldoc.url = "my.url.com" Then

        Do Until htmldoc.url = "my.url.com/get"  'this gives me access denied when stepping out
            My.Application.DoEvents()

            Try
                htmldoc = axWeb.Document.frames("Frame1").document

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try


        Loop
```

Comment: So... what are you trying to do?

Comment: Essentially I am automating a web page, data is input, and normally it goes to the /get page, but sometimes it will not, and you need to manually click (or i suppose programatically click a link) but I need to wait until the page is at the proper location ("/get" URL) before running the program further. I suppose I could make a do loop to wait for an element only found on the "/get" page and include a timeout... not sure what options I have